# apt-daily.service timer-activated. Still need to "enable" apt-update in 20auto-upgrades?

Tags: apt, systemd, services, unattended-upgrades

Question summary: Why do I have to configure 20auto-upgrades to do an update of the package lists, although I am already running apt-daily.service systemd-timer-based?
If I don't, then unattended-upgrades won't find anything to upgrade.

In my ubuntu 20.04 I have apt-daily configured the following:

apt-daily.timer:

```
OnCalendar=*-*-* 6,18:00
```

apt-daily.service has of course:

```
ExecStart=/usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily update
```

I guess this means: Do something like apt-get update every day at 6 am and 6 pm.

My journald confirms the executions of these (time of the day not matching though):

```
May 01 02:50:22 nb-lubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt download activities...
May 01 02:50:27 nb-lubuntu systemd[1]: apt-daily.service: Succeeded.
May 01 02:50:27 nb-lubuntu systemd[1]: Finished Daily apt download activities.
```

Nevertheless I had the issue that my unattended-upgrades call never found any need to install/upgrade anything unless I started apt-get update manually prior to unattended-upgrades.
That issue was fixed by specifying in

/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades.conf:

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "1";
```

Why was the daily update by apt-daily.timer / apt-daily.service not sufficient?

Comment: Good question. The apt setting predates the systemd timer. And some folks (like [devuan](https://www.devuan.org/) users) have apt but not systemd. But, fundamentally, apt and systemd are separate upstream projects, each set of developers created a different on/off switch, so all the various switches must be 'on' for the feature to work.

Comment: I take it as: There is redundancy, and it could be, that the systemd timer is irrelevant. But to avoid hassles I set all flags to be set to "Go". And your example sounds plausible. @user535733: Thanks!

Comment: @user535733: But: Doesn't the command "apt.systemd.daily update" coded inside the systemd timer/service pair simply execute the update? It's a service, not a parameter. Or does the command also rely on the conf parameters?

Comment: See the script /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily. Systemd merely launches that script and monitors for success/failure. That script launches apt. Apt loads all the apt settings when it launches...and can perhaps be stopped there by the apt switch (have not tried it). The result of that script is reported back to systemd as success or failure.

Comment: Plausible again! I didn't realize, that apt.systemd.daily is merely a script. I should have tried to open it. Thanks